# Redirection in laravel not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and want to redirect to another view using button.
On clicking button I want to redirect to particular route function and then to controller.
But I am making some mistake.I did what they showed online but couldn't rectify.
Following is my code.

Controller:

```
class MyController extends BaseController{
    function fromSub(){
        return view('from');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('from',array('uses'=>'MyController@fromSub' , 'as' => 'from'));
```

View:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button"  onclick="window.location='{{ url("from") }}'">BUTTON</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

replace this code in route and test it:

**Laravel 5.1+**:

```
Route::get('from', 'MyController@fromSub')->name('from');
```

**Laravel 5.1** :

```
Route::get('from', [
    'as' => 'from', 'uses' => 'MyController@fromSub'
]);
```

Comment: it is still not working Mohammad.When I am checking in console it is showing some red dots i.e error in view

Comment: which version of laravel you use? what is the error text exactly?